# Deleting Row if only <Node 1> exists, Delete only <Node 1> if <Node 2> <Node 3> exsist

Tags: sql, xml, plsql

Consider below table with 2 rows.

```
ID_NUM      | GENERAL_DATA
0100        | <...><UpdateServices><AddServices><RemoveServices><...>
0200        | <...><UpdateServices><...>
```

My questions are:

How to delete the row if XML has node `<UpdateServices>` only (meaning `<AddServices>` and `<RemoveServices>` are not present)? and

How to delete node `<UpdateServices>` from the XML if `<AddServices>` and `<RemoveServices>` are present?

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE AS
  select '0100' as id_num,
  XMLTYPE('<TRX>
  <DATA>
      <Request APIType="null">
          <SubscriberIdsInfo>
              <ExternalId>
                  <ExternalId>0100</ExternalId>
              </ExternalId>
              <SubscriberId>
                  <SubscrNumber/>
              </SubscriberId>
          </SubscriberIdsInfo>
          <UpdateServices>
              <Soc>ABC</Soc>
              <ServiceAgreementSequenceNo/>
              <DealerCode/>
              <DeployMode/>
              <EffectiveDate>2019-10-16T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpirationDate/>
              <OfferInstanceId/>
          </UpdateServices>
          <AddServices>
              <Soc>ABC1</Soc>
              <ServiceAgreementSequenceNo/>
              <DealerCode/>
              <DeployMode/>
              <EffectiveDate>2018-10-16T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpirationDate/>
              <OfferInstanceId/>
          </AddServices>
          <RemoveServices>
              <Soc>ABC2</Soc>
              <ServiceAgreementSequenceNo/>
              <DealerCode/>
              <DeployMode/>
              <EffectiveDate>2017-10-16T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpirationDate/>
              <OfferInstanceId/>
          </RemoveServices>
          <SubParameters>
              <Name>PoolID</Name>
              <Values>POOL0100</Values>
              <EffectiveDate>2014-10-16T14:08:37</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpirationDate/>
          </SubParameters>
          <ActivityInfo/>
      </Request>
  </DATA>
  </TRX>') general_data from dual;


 insert into SAMPLE_TABLE (id_num,general_data)
  select  '0200' as id_num, 
  XMLTYPE('<TRX>
  <DATA>
      <Request APIType="null">
          <SubscriberIdsInfo>
              <ExternalId>
                  <ExternalId>0200</ExternalId>
              </ExternalId>
              <SubscriberId>
                  <SubscrNumber/>
              </SubscriberId>
          </SubscriberIdsInfo>
          <UpdateServices>
              <Soc>ABC</Soc>
              <ServiceAgreementSequenceNo/>
              <DealerCode/>
              <DeployMode/>
              <EffectiveDate>2019-10-16T00:00:00</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpirationDate/>
              <OfferInstanceId/>
          </UpdateServices>
          <SubParameters>
              <Name>PoolID</Name>
              <Values>POOL0200</Values>
              <EffectiveDate>2014-10-16T14:08:37</EffectiveDate>
              <ExpirationDate/>
          </SubParameters>
          <ActivityInfo/>
      </Request>
  </DATA>
  </TRX>') general_data from dual;


commit;
```

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

**How to delete the row** if XML has node `<UpdateServices>` only (meaning `<AddServices>` and `<RemoveServices>` are not present)?

```
delete from sample_table X
where xmlExists('//UpdateServices' passing X.general_data)
    and not xmlExists('//AddServices|//RemoveServices' passing X.general_data)
;
```

**How to delete node `<UpdateServices>`** from the XML if `<AddServices>` and `<RemoveServices>` are present?

```
update sample_table X
set X.general_data = deleteXml(X.general_data, '//UpdateServices')
where xmlExists('//AddServices' passing X.general_data)
    and xmlExists('//RemoveServices' passing X.general_data)
;
```

**Note:** I believe the latter can be more effectively done via XQuery, but since I (still) don't know that language, I can provide only the `deleteXml()` solution.